# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement airflow-provider-kafka (from versions: none)

Tags: python

I am not able install the "pip install airflow-provider-kafka" package in airflow , I have upgraded python version from 3.6.9 to 3.7.5 , but it is giving saeme error.

give me a solution for this

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
pip install -Iv airflow-provider-kafka==0.2.2
```

to force a specific version to install.